# Android popup menu bug position when keyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, keyboard, position, popupmenu

I make a popup menu on clicking a button by code below, however the popup menu is overlapping with keyboard on API 26.

```
@OnClick(R.id.imageview_add_attachment)
public void onClickAddAttachment(View view){
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu_select_pictures, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.show();
}
```

and this code works fine with API 23 when keyboard is open:

[image]

However with Android O (API 26) the same code doesn't shows in correct location:

[image]

what I tried:
 - Changing android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu to android.widget.PopupMenu.
 - I create the popup menu on onCreate and just show it on button clicked.

Note:
I'm using android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity. and I'm using these styles:

```
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

What can I do to fix the position of popup menu? Should I manually put the position? is this a bug with popupmenu or I'm doing something wrong? 
I'm just wondering if that is a bug because this is written in [PopupMenu Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) :

> If the IME is visible the popup will not overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will dismiss it.

Comment: before opening popup close the keyboard may it will solve your problem

Comment: yea that might work. but is this a bug?

Comment: its not a bug .PopupMenu Documentation already says that If the IME is visible the popup will not overlap it until it is touched. Touching outside of the popup will dismiss it.

Comment: I think that Position Default Value is changed. But you can using showAsDropDown